# Change event handler firing only once, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I'm trying to execute my code when I select an element in the my dropdown menu. I'm using jQuery's change(). My problem is that once I execute the function the first time. It will not respond to any other selected items (aka other changes). I made test block at the bottom and that code does fire on every change. What am I doing wrong in my first change code?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nysteve/QHumL/#base

Side question; I noticed that when I ask a question and select an answer, some of them appear on my profile and some questions do not even though I selected an answer. Does it take time for them to register?

```
function timeToHexColor() {
    var color = Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999);
    if (color >= 0 && color <= 9 || color >= 1000 && color <= 9999) {
        color = "#00" + color;
    } else if (color >= 10 && color <= 99 || color >= 10000 && color <= 99999) {
        color = "#0" + color;
    } else if (color >= 100 && color <= 999) {
        color = "#000" + color;
    } else if (color > 999999) {
        color = "#" + (color - 1);
    } else {
        color = "#" + color;
    }
    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML += 
        "<div  style='border:solid 1px white;color:white;background-color:" + color + ";'>" + color + "</div>";
}

function Colors(interval) {
    this.interval = interval;
    switch (this.interval) {
        case 'second':
            document.getElementById('options').disabled = true;
            x = setInterval(timeToHexColor, 1000);
            setTimeout(stopColors, 10000);
            break;
        case 'minute':
            x = setInterval(timeToHexColor, 60000);
            document.getElementById('options').disabled = true;
            break;
        case 'hour':
            x = setInterval(timeToHexColor, 60000 * 60);
            document.getElementById('options').disabled = true;
            break;
        case 'day':
            x = setInterval(timeToHexColor, 1000);
            document.getElementById('options').disabled = true;
            setTimeout(stopColors, 10000);
            break;
        default:
            alert(this.interval + " is not a valid interval option");
            break;
    }
}

function stopColors() {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById('options').disabled = false;

}

$("#options").prop('selectedIndex', -1);
//this will only fire once and that's it. Is it process getting halted?
$("#options").change(function () {
    Colors($("#options").val());
});


// This test  will fire on change every time.
$("#x").change(function () {
    alert($("#x").val());
});
```

Comment: can you share the html also

Comment: Updated the question with the JSfiddle link as well: http://jsfiddle.net/nysteve/QHumL/#base

Comment: Your `options` dropdown is disabling itself everytime the `Colors' function is processed.

Comment: I was/am trying to disable the control while the function is firing. The reason I'm doing this is because it seems that if I pick another item from the dropdown while the first set of colors did not finish printing, the next round goes on printing infinitely.

Comment: I also just tried removing the disable property and click the dropdown after, still won't fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why but your document.getElementById was interfering with clear interval and causing jQuery to be unresponsive.

```
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML += 
    "<div  style='border:solid 1px white;color:white;background-color:" + color + ";'>" + color + "</div>";
```

If you append it using jQuery instead you don't have the problem.

```
 $("#container").append("<div  style='border:solid 1px white;color:white;background-color:" + color + ";'>" + color + "</div>");
```

I also added 100 miliseconds to your set timeout so that your function would run ten times instead of 9.

```
 setTimeout(stopColors, 10100);
```

Check out the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/QHumL/50/

Comment: Also if you want the other options `besides seconds` to ever stop you need to add an appropriate `setTimeout(stopColors, 600100);` for the rest.

Comment: That is strange @Trevor, I hope someone could figure that on in this thread, and thank you for the jQ answer!